# Get UDP datagram length via Boost Asio?

Tags: c++, header, udp, boost-asio, packet

Is it possible to get the length of the UDP datagram via Boost Asio? UDP headers have a field that specifies the length of the UDP packet. Is it possible to get this value via Boost Asio? If not, how does one determine the length of the packet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asio` allows you to bind completion handlers when executing reads. One of the arguments of the completion handler is the packet length.

Your completion handler for a read must meet the requirements specified in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html

For example look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_udp_echo_server.cpp. In the call to `async_receive_from` you specify which completion handler is to be called once the read completes:

```
socket_.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length), sender_endpoint_,
    boost::bind(&server::handle_receive_from, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Thus when the completion handler `handle_receive_from` is executed, asio passes the size of the bytes read to the handler.

```
void handle_receive_from(const boost::system::error_code& error,
  size_t bytes_recvd)
```

Comment: The blocking calls `receive` and `receive_from` also have that information as their return value. And if you want to know without actually reading the data, you could use `available` but that will not return the size of the next datagram but the number of bytes that are waiting to be read at the socket at all.

Comment: @DeVadder For UDP, `available()` returns the number of bytes of the next datagram.  The subtle detail is that `available()` returns the number of bytes available for _reading_, and `receive()` will only dequeue a single datagram.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! Both Ralf and DeVadder gave the answers I'm looking for.

Comment: @Tanner Sansbury: I did some science (tested it) and turns out, you are completely right. I even used `available()` once to check whether my socket had more than one datagram waiting to detect if my server was too slow with writing the received packets. Guess i got lucky there that that never happened as the server would have been oblivious to it.